# How to implement drawer navigator in each tab?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5, react-navigation-drawer, react-navigation-bottom-tab

I want to have drawer navigation in each tab and I followed this approach, but it doesn't work when I switch back to the previous tab (maybe some navigation tree issue).

[image]

As you can see above, the drawer works fine for the first time in each tab, but when I go back to any already navigated tab and try to open the drawer, the drawer doesn't open for that tab but opens up for the just previous tab. I think there's some navigation issue.

**HomeBottomTab.js**

Here, I created a Bottom Tab Navigator and called the drawers for each tab.

```js
const HomeBottomTab = ({ navigation }) => {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator ... >
      <Tab.Screen name="Notifications" component={NotificationsDrawer} ... />
      <Tab.Screen name="Tutorials" component={TutorialsDrawer} ... />
      <Tab.Screen name="Wallet" component={WalletDrawer} ... />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  )
}
```

**NotificationsDrawer.js**

Here I created a Drawer Navigator for the Notifications tab.

```js
export default function NotificationsDrawer({ navigation }) {
    return (
      <Drawer.Navigator ... >
        <Drawer.Screen ... />
        <Drawer.Screen ... />
        <Drawer.Screen ... />
      </Drawer.Navigator>
    )
}
```

I did the same for **TutorialsDrawer** and **WalletDrawer**. Is there any way to fix this? Have I done something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I had to do was create an independent **Navigation Container** and a **Stack Navigator** inside of it, which contains a **Stack Screen** and it accepts the drawer as a component.

```js
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
```

```js
const Stack = createStackNavigator();
```

```js
function Notifications_Drawer({ navigation }) {
 return (
  <Drawer.Navigator ... >
      <Drawer.Screen ... />
      <Drawer.Screen ... />
      <Drawer.Screen ... />
  </Drawer.Navigator>
 )
}
```

```js
export default function NotificationsDrawer() {
    return (
        <NavigationContainer independent={true}>
            <Stack.Navigator>
                <Stack.Screen
                    name="Notifications_Drawer"
                    component={Notifications_Drawer}
                    options={{ headerShown: false }}
                />
            </Stack.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
    );
}
```